# change the background of an image in image magick

Tags: imagemagick

I am using this command for imagemagick to extend the size of an image and background to white

```
convert input.png -extent 495X320 -gravity center  -background white output.jpg
```

The size is doing extent but the background is black every time. I tried many methods but the same black is coming every time.So can some one help me how to solve this. Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order is important here, use `-background` before `-extent`:

```
convert input.png -background white -extent 495X320 -gravity center output.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this for people that have tried the other answer but it still does not work.

In my case I needed

```
convert image.png -resize 80% -quality 80% -background white image-edited.jpg
```

Add the `-flatten` option at the end and it should work. So like:

```
convert image.jpg -resize 80% -quality 80% -background white -flatten image-edited.jpg
```